# How to clear an entire page when reset button is pressed?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Im a newbie in visualforce. May I ask on how to clear the entire page in visualforce when user click on reset button.

[image: Reset Button]

[image: How to clear page]

Your piece of code is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**: code is

```
<apex:commandButton value="Reset" status="idStatus" onclick="this.form.reset();return false;" />
```

Comment: use referencevaraible.clear() or try to load the page once again ,like refer same page using pagereference method

Comment: Can you please paste your existing code?

Comment: @Ferdinand, if you post code of your attempt(s) at implementing a solution of your own for this, the community is more likely to assist you in solving any problems with your code. Currently, it appears that you are asking the community to do your work for you and does not show any real effort in researching a solution.

Comment: My code is not sufficient to paste here. here is my piece of code <apex:commandButton value="Reset" status="idStatus"  onclick="this.form.reset();return false;" />.  this code is only clear the first block. What I want is to clear all in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using commandButton's action and rerender? You could put both blocks in a div and rerender it after reset all the value in a controller.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!resetValueAction}" value="Reset" reRender="bothBlockDiv" />
```

Or if you want to use Javascript and you have set an id for each input element, you could try something like:

```
document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = '';
```